# Do the Quotation based on having commas and quotation in columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data frame contains two columns

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 22,34 | "Book",2 |
| 12,40 | "Note",6 |
| 12 | 20 |

I want to check the data frame if columns have commas in between like 22,34 or have something like "Book",2 then put **Quotation** around them.
The final result must be like this :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| "22,34" | "'Book',2" |
| "12,40" | "'Note',6" |
| 12 | 20 |

Comment: To clarify, is `df.loc[[1],['B']] = "'Book 2', 2"` valid? or must it be `df.loc[[1],['B']] = "\"Book 2\",2"`?

Comment: Would you include the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Yes, this is valid. the data type is gonna be Object at the end.

Comment: Would you provide the output of your starting `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Thank you, but as you can see in your final result 22,34 is changing like this "22",40  but I am looking for "22,40" and same for the second column.

Comment: fixed, I believe. May I ask, why is this transformation necessary? Does this have something to do with writing data to a CSV file? Are you able to change the delimeter?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp This is actually for researchers who just put their data in their CSV file based on their desire so in order to save their data for further processing I want to have a clear understanding of their data. By the way, It's working Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
#starting df
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '22,34',    1: '12,40',    2: '12'},
                       'B': {0: '"Book",2', 1: '"Note",6', 2: '20'}})
>>> df
       A         B
0  22,34  "Book",2
1  12,40  "Note",6
2     12        20

>>> for column in df.columns:
        df.loc[:,column] = df.loc[:,column].transform(lambda x: 
            x if "," not in x else 
            "\"" + x + "\"")
>>> df
         A           B
0  "22,34"  ""Book",2"
1  "12,40"  ""Note",6"
2       12          20

#result df
>>> df.to_dict()
{'A': {0: '"22,34"',    1: '"12,40"',    2: '12'}, 
 'B': {0: '""Book",2"', 1: '""Note",6"', 2: '20'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on @Joshua's answer. You don't need to loop through all columns, just use `df.applymap` on the whole DataFrame .

This one line of code does the job aswell.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if "," not in x else "\"" + x + "\"")
```